# Creating a Format File for Bulk Import

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a Format File to bulk import a .csv file but i, am getting an error.

Query I used

```
"BCP -SMSSQLSERVER01.[Internal_Checks].[Jan_Flat] format out -fC:\Desktop\exported data\Jan_FlatFormat.fmt -c -T -Uasda -SMSSQLSERVER01 -PPASSWORD"
```

I am getting an error

> "A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options."

This is the error. can anyone suggest what need to do.

Comment: That looks more like <sql-server> than <mysql>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) documentation the first parameter should be a `[Database.]Schema.{Table | View | "query"}`, so don't put `-SMSSQLSERVER01` where you've got it. Also use `format nul` instead of `format out`.

Try using:

```
bcp.exe [Internal_Checks].[Jan_Flat] format nul "-fC:\Desktop\exported data\Jan_FlatFormat.fmt" -c -SMSSQLSERVER01 -T -Uasda -PPASSWORD
```

Note the quotes `"` around the `-f` switch because your path name contains space characters.

Also note that the `-c` switch causes single-byte characters (ASCII/OEM/codepage with `SQLCHAR`) to be written out. If your table contains `nchar`, `nvarchar` or `ntext` columns you should consider using the `-w` switch instead so as to write out UTF-16 encoded data (using `SQLNCHAR`).